# Prolog list problem

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

```
[a,b,c,d] and
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[43,34,56,5],[23,32,2,2]]
```

I want to make

```
[[a,1,2,3,4],[b,5,6,7,8],[c,43,34,56,5],[d,23,32,2,2]]
```

I use swi prolog is it possible do it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
solve([], [], []).

solve([[X|Y]|S], [X|L1], [Y|L2]):-
  solve(S, L1, L2).
```

**UPDATE:** How to use

Write the function in a file "a.pl", then in swi-prolog type:

```
['a.pl'].
```

then type:

```
solve(X, [a,b,c,d], [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[43,34,56,5],[23,32,2,2]]).
```

You will get:

```
X = [[a, 1, 2, 3, 4], [b, 5, 6, 7, 8], [c, 43, 34, 56, 5], [d, 23, 32, 2, 2]]
```

I have the strange feeling that I am doing your homework. Is it?

Comment: The solution is in the first parameter, then the 2 lists you mentionned. I hope you are not asking people to do your homeworks.

Comment: Swi prolog only answers "false." to that question.

Comment: let me install swi-prolog, I will try. Did you understand the logic?

Comment: You are correct I made a mistake when testing your solution. I apologise.

Answer (score 2):

Use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and [Prolog lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) like this:

```
?- As  = [a,b,c,d], 
   Bss = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[43,34,56,5],[23,32,2,2]],
   maplist(\H^T^[H|T]^true,As,Bss,Css).
As  = [ a         , b         , c            , d           ],
Bss = [[  1,2,3,4],[  5,6,7,8],[  43,34,56,5],[  23,32,2,2]],
Css = [[a,1,2,3,4],[b,5,6,7,8],[c,43,34,56,5],[d,23,32,2,2]].
```

---

#### Edit

Different lambda terms can be used in above `maplist/4` goal, as pointed out in a comment.

- `maplist(\H^T^[H|T]^true,As,Bss,Css)`
- `maplist(\H^T^ =([H|T]) ,As,Bss,Css)`

Comment: Alternatively: `..., maplist(\H^T^ =([H|T]),As,Bss,Cs).`

Comment: @false. Smart! Nice combination of lambda args + compound (for partial application of goal). Should be part of a Prolog lambda tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

SWI Prolog can do this with two short predicates:

```
merge0(A, B, Prev, Next) :- append(Prev, [[A|B]], Next).
merge(A, B, Result) :- foldl(merge0, A, B, [], Result).
```

Here is example of input and output:

```
a(X) :- X = [a,b,c,d].
b(X) :- X = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[43,34,56,5],[23,32,2,2]].

?- a(A), b(B), merge(A, B, Result).

Result = [[a, 1, 2, 3, 4], [b, 5, 6, 7, 8], [c, 43, 34, 56, 5], [d, 23, 32, 2, 2]].
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
delete(X, [X|T], T).

delete(X, [Y|T], [Y|L]):-
delete(X, T, L).

insert(X, List, BigList):-
  delete(X, BigList, List).

if([],X,X).

if([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[SH|ST]):-
  insert(H1,H2,SH),!,
  if(T1,T2,ST).
```

I doubled checked, it works.

"if" stands for "insert first".

Comment: Seems overly complex and imperative-style to me.

Comment: well It is an example of using the "cut" posibility:)